# Allow Multiple Chips with the same value in a v-combobox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

how can I add new chips with the same value in the Combobox that I am using? For example every time I add 200 and I want to add another 200 it is automatically deleted.
I want to save the user inputs in an array like [100, 200, 200, 300]

```
<v-combobox
  v-if="points.number_compartments > 1"
  v-model="compartments_detail"
  chips
  label="CAPACIDAD DE COMPARTIMIENTOS"
  clearable
  deletable-chips
  append-icon=""
  multiple
  outlined
  dense
  class="mx-3"
 >
  <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, selected, index }">
    <v-chip
     small
     v-bind="attrs"
     :input-value="selected"
     close
     @click:close="removeChips(index)"
     color="primary"
     >
       <span>{{index + 1}} </span>  - {{ item }} <span class="mx-1"> (gls) </span>
     </v-chip>
   </template>
 </v-combobox>
```

[image]

Comment: first thing, why do you want to add 200, 2 times? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: The field is for the user to specify the capacity of the compartments, and sometimes it can happen that two compartments have the same measurement.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use duplicated items, it's better to use an **array of objects data structure** and give every duplicate item a unique value so the items can be identified by the `item-value` prop and allow selecting duplicates.

The component code would be like this-

```
<v-combobox
  v-if="points.number_compartments > 1"
  :items="items"
  item-text="label"
  item-value="id"
  v-model="compartments_detail"
  chips
  label="CAPACIDAD DE COMPARTIMIENTOS"
  clearable
  deletable-chips
  append-icon=""
  multiple
  outlined
  dense
  class="mx-3"
 >
   <-- YOUR CODE ->
 </v-combobox>
```

And the structure of the items would be-

```
items: [
  {
    label: 100,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    label: 100,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    label: 200,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    label: 200,
    id: 4
  }
]
```